# in KDE 5 how to make a GUI application show/hide with a shortcut similar to Tilda/guake/yakuake

Tags: gnome, kde, xfce, window-manager, plasma5

I simply want to setup Emacs GUI to toggle (hide/show) visibility just like we see in guake, tilda or yakuake terminals(it is called drop down in these terminals). for example I am working with Emacs within the GUI and I have a browser window behind it, I want to hide Emacs GUI with a shortcut(e.g F12) and then see my browser (with focus) interact with or any other window, then again press F12 and I will have my Emacs GUI back(I am running KDE 5.13). Also if you know how to do this in XFCE or gnome please share your knowledge.

Comment: This question might help, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136708/recover-gui-window-after-minimizing-in-ratpoison

Answer (score 2):

I have asked this question on emacs.stackexchange as well in this [link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44100/how-to-make-emacs-gui-behave-like-guake-tilda-yakuake). I will copy the anser here for reference. It relied on X11 to work and needs xdotool and wmctrl installed.

```
#!/bin/bash
######################################################################################################
# This script will toggle minimize/activate first window with specified class
# If window not found program will be launched
#
# window class can be found with next programs:
#   wmctrl -x -l
#   xprop
# No credit taken.......... Cannot read the original.....
# Found on http://blog.sokolov.me/2014/06/20/linuxx11-toggle-window-minimizemaximize/
# in Russian :) but works when adjusting the wrapping.
######################################################################################################
NEEDED_WINDOW_CLASS="emacs.Emacs"
LAUNCH_PROGRAM="emacs"
######################################################################################################
NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_HEX=`wmctrl -x -l | grep ${NEEDED_WINDOW_CLASS} | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1`
NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_DEC=$((${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_HEX}))
if [ -z "${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_HEX}" ]; then
${LAUNCH_PROGRAM}
else
echo "Found window ID:${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_DEC}(0x${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_HEX})"
ACIVE_WINDOW_DEC=`xdotool getactivewindow`
if [ "${ACIVE_WINDOW_DEC}" == "${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_DEC}" ]; then
    xdotool windowminimize ${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_DEC}
else
    xdotool windowactivate ${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_DEC}
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Not sure if it's something new in `xdotool`, but I was able to use `xdotool search --sync --class FooBar` to get the decimal window ID of target directly instead of calling `wmctrl`.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but wanted to post an answer here that isn't KDE or gnome specific but instead relies on two apps that interact with the underlying display server/window managers (i.e. X11 or Wayland) to get the the job done.

Tested in Ubuntu, should work anywhere you can install `wmctrl` and `xdotool`. This example uses the `konsole` terminal app, but you could use any application you know the class name of. To figure out the class name, open the application and run `wmctrl -lx`.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# if app is not open then launch it -- remove this if you don't want your
# shortcut to launch the application if it hasn't been launched yet
if [ -z "$(xdotool search --class konsole)" ]; then
  konsole
fi

# get current focused window and visible konsole window
CLASS="konsole"
ACTIVE_WINDOW="$(xdotool getactivewindow)"
APP_WINDOW="$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class $CLASS)"

# if focused, minimize and hide the konsole, otherwise bring konsole to current desktop and open
if [ "$ACTIVE_WINDOW" = "$APP_WINDOW" ]; then
  xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
else
  wmctrl -xR "$CLASS"
fi
```

This script assumes a few things, namely:

1. that `$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class yourApp)` returns a single match (you'll need to handle arrays/multiple matches)
2. that you want to immediately switch to the raised (shown) GUI application
3. that your target application isn't running purely as a daemon/service (won't be registered as a window inside X11 or Wayland otherwise)
4. that you want the application to appear on whatever desktop space you are currently on

If you don't want 2 and 4 you can use `xdotool` alone, I just wanted to more closely emulate the behaviour of Guake terminal's show/hide behaviour, hence using `wmctrl` to bring and show the GUI application to the currently active desktop.

Since it's a bash script it's portable - i.e. you need only figure out how to set a custom shortcut inside your desktop application (KDE, Gnome, etc) and run the script using said shortcut.

KDE's docs on making custom keyboard [shortcuts are here](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/khelpcenter/fundamentals/shortcuts.html), Gnome docs on [shortcuts are here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en).